# Twitter Bootstrap way to normalize image sizes?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap to do a site for a realtor and the MLS images are all kinds of wacky sizes, which is giving me a funky layout.  What would be the best way to handle this so the text starts from the same position in each row?

Is there a good solution in css/js or should I make a copy of the images after some imagemagick processing that standardizes the aspect ratios?

http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/1055/ and source below

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span4">
            <h4>123 Happy Tree Lane</h4>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/767x575" class="img-rounded"/>
            <p>A-list networks niches ROI tagclouds architect, users strategic granular applications maximize functionalities streamline</p>
            <p><a class="btn" href="#">View Details &raquo;</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="span4">
            <h4>666 Doomsday Road</h4>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/400x266" class="img-rounded"/>
            <p>Semantic e-tailers networks users user-contributed action-items. E-commerce architectures networking envisioneer next-generation</p>
            <p><a class="btn" href="#">View Details &raquo;</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="span4">
            <h4>000 asdf</h4>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/768x511" class="img-rounded"/>
            <p>Productize e-tailers users redefine e-business synergize bandwidth user-contributed, "front-end reintermediate,"</p>
            <p><a class="btn" href="#">View Details &raquo;</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</diV>
```

Comment: ImageMagick will probably be the easiest, IMO.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one idea to get you started: http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/sukH8/

You will see I've specified a new class

```
.imageClip{
width:300px;
height:175px;
overflow:hidden;
}
```

and then applied this class to all the images. You would just need to play with the height and width of in .imageClip to suit your purpose, and you could also use different values via @media requests for narrow screen widths as well.

Hope this helps